# Can we use System.Data.OracleClient for sending a List<> to the Oracle stored procedure? 

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I have a requirement to send couple of `List<>` objects to the Oracle store procedure. I can do it using ODP.

But I just want to confirm that can it be possible with the `System.Data.OracleClient`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.OracleClient` does not accept Lists as parameters to stored procedures. In fact, it doesn't allow standard Arrays either. Really the only thing you can do is serialize the data encapsulated in the List and pass it into the stored procedure as a String (Varchar2) and then split it within the procedure. But that really depends on what sort of data your Lists contain, and how dynamic it is.